# Multiplying columns from two different Dataframes with specific condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset of women of childbearing age and above with nearly 500,000 individuals.

```
sample <-
 structure(list(iD = c(1, 2), age = c(68, 40), born_1 = c(14, 
 1), born_2 = c(9, NA), born_3 = c(4, NA), born_4 = c(0, NA), 
     asfr15 = c(0, 0), asfr16 = c(7.40444, 7.40444), asfr17 = c(42.87749, 
     7.40444), asfr18 = c(73.05321, 7.40444), asfr19 = c(98.28869, 
     7.40444), asfr20 = c(144.9568, 7.40444), asfr21 = c(164.976, 
     180.28), asfr22 = c(180.28, 180.28), asfr23 = c(191.304, 
     180.28), asfr24 = c(200.199, 180.28), asfr25 = c(200.2018, 
     180.28), asfr26 = c(200.2007, 180.28), asfr27 = c(200.392, 
     180.28), asfr28 = c(197.684, 180.28), asfr29 = c(193.7632, 
     180.28), asfr30 = c(187.6072, 180.28), asfr31 = c(179.5616, 
     180.28), asfr32 = c(170.5096, 180.28), asfr33 = c(160.8376, 
     180.28), asfr34 = c(150.484, 180.28), asfr35 = c(139.3304, 
     180.28), asfr36 = c(127.796, 180.28), asfr37 = c(115.028, 
     180.28), asfr38 = c(100.72, 180.28), asfr39 = c(85.6256, 
     180.28), asfr40 = c(182.4384, 180.28), asfr41 = c(178.412, 
     180.28), asfr42 = c(171.928, 180.28), asfr43 = c(163.316, 
     180.28), asfr44 = c(152.9056, 180.28), asfr45 = c(141.0264, 
     180.28), asfr46 = c(128.008, 180.28), asfr47 = c(114.18, 
     180.28), asfr48 = c(99.872, 180.28), asfr49 = c(85.4136, 
     180.28)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))

sample1 <-
 structure(list(age = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53), L = c(0.986675438, 0.98702345, 
 0.98637393, 0.98578905, 0.9852613, 0.98478356, 0.9843488, 0.98394965, 
 0.98357788, 0.98322392, 0.98287637, 0.98252143, 0.98214247, 0.9817192, 
 0.9812277, 0.98064228, 0.97994116, 0.97911745, 0.97818632, 0.97718334, 
 0.97615046, 0.97511987, 0.97410767, 0.97311336, 0.97212658, 0.97113462, 
 0.97012689, 0.9690984, 0.96804964, 0.96698351, 0.96590219, 0.96480536, 
 0.96368905, 0.96254573, 0.96136596, 0.96014053, 0.9588627, 0.95752879, 
 0.95613703, 0.954686, 0.95317327, 0.95159409, 0.94993984, 0.94819731, 
 0.94634926, 0.94437608, 0.94225687, 0.93996942, 0.93748997, 0.93479226, 
 0.93184638, 0.92861614, 0.92506109, 0.92114516)), class = c("tbl_df", 
 "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -54L))
```

Considering the first woman is my sample with ID number 1.  She is 68 years old. For this woman, I need asfrs from 15 to 49 multiplied by the probability of dying from that age until the year in which data were collected (2016).

For instance, the first woman [ asfr15] must be multiplied by [(1- L 53)], since if a 68-year-old woman has a child at age 15, her child must be 53 years old by the time data is collected, and so on.

> Asfr16* [(1- L 52)]
>
> Asfr 17* [(1- L 51)]

and so on for each age.

For the second woman, since she has 40 years old. I she had a child in age 15, her child by the time of census (2016) would be 25-year-old. Thus, we need to multiply asfr15 by * [(1- L25)].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach may look like so. By reshaping to long we can easily use a `left_join` to merge the `L` column based on the child's age.

```r
library(tidyverse)

sample |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("asfr")) |>
  mutate(age_child = age - readr::parse_number(name)) |>
  left_join(sample1, by = c("age_child" = "age")) |>
  mutate(value = value * (1 - L)) |>
  select(-age_child, -L) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 41
#>      iD   age born_1 born_2 born_3 born_4 asfr15 asfr16 asfr17 asfr18 asfr19
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1    68     14      9      4      0      0  0.555  3.06   4.98   6.41 
#> 2     2    40      1     NA     NA     NA      0  0.206  0.199  0.192  0.184
#> # ℹ 30 more variables: asfr20 <dbl>, asfr21 <dbl>, asfr22 <dbl>, asfr23 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr24 <dbl>, asfr25 <dbl>, asfr26 <dbl>, asfr27 <dbl>, asfr28 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr29 <dbl>, asfr30 <dbl>, asfr31 <dbl>, asfr32 <dbl>, asfr33 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr34 <dbl>, asfr35 <dbl>, asfr36 <dbl>, asfr37 <dbl>, asfr38 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr39 <dbl>, asfr40 <dbl>, asfr41 <dbl>, asfr42 <dbl>, asfr43 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr44 <dbl>, asfr45 <dbl>, asfr46 <dbl>, asfr47 <dbl>, asfr48 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr49 <dbl>
```

However, while this works for your example data I'm afraid that it not that efficient for your huge dataset. Hence, here is a matrix based approach. Basically I first create a matrix of `L` values where each row reflects the respective values based on the mother's age and with names corresponding to the `asfr` columns. Afterwards we can multiply the `asfr` columns by this matrix.

```
L_mat <- sapply(sample$age, \(age) {
  L <- c(rep(NA, 35), sample1$L) # 35 = 49 - 15 + 1
  names(L) <- c(-rev(seq_len(35)), sample1$age)
  L[as.character(age - 15:49)]
}) |>
  t()
colnames(L_mat) <- paste0("L", 15:49)

sample[paste0("asfr", 15:49)] <-
  sample[paste0("asfr", 15:49)] * (1 - L_mat)
sample
#> # A tibble: 2 × 41
#>      iD   age born_1 born_2 born_3 born_4 asfr15 asfr16 asfr17 asfr18 asfr19
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1    68     14      9      4      0      0  0.555  3.06   4.98   6.41 
#> 2     2    40      1     NA     NA     NA      0  0.206  0.199  0.192  0.184
#> # ℹ 30 more variables: asfr20 <dbl>, asfr21 <dbl>, asfr22 <dbl>, asfr23 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr24 <dbl>, asfr25 <dbl>, asfr26 <dbl>, asfr27 <dbl>, asfr28 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr29 <dbl>, asfr30 <dbl>, asfr31 <dbl>, asfr32 <dbl>, asfr33 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr34 <dbl>, asfr35 <dbl>, asfr36 <dbl>, asfr37 <dbl>, asfr38 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr39 <dbl>, asfr40 <dbl>, asfr41 <dbl>, asfr42 <dbl>, asfr43 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr44 <dbl>, asfr45 <dbl>, asfr46 <dbl>, asfr47 <dbl>, asfr48 <dbl>,
#> #   asfr49 <dbl>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will work, though I am *sure* there are more elegant solutions - first created a "helper" function that will identify the columns needing to be modified depending on the age and modify them according to your description (`asfrN * (1-L[age])`). Then I `split` into a list based on ID and applied the function across the list, combining it back together again with `do.call`

```
helperFun <- function(x){
  asfr <- paste0("asfr", 15:min((x$age - 15), 49))
  x[asfr] <- lapply(x[asfr], \(y) 
                    y * (1-(sample1[sample1$age == (x$age - 15),"L"])))
  x
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(sample, sample$iD), helperFun))
```

Although difficult to demonstrate here because of the width of your sample data, only the age-appropriate columns are modified in your ordinal `sample` data.

Below I output columns asfr15-18 and 22-28 to show that transformations stop at the correct column for ID #2:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 13
#      iD   age asfr15$L asfr16$L asfr17$L asfr18$L asfr22$L asfr23$L asfr24$L asfr25$L asfr26$L asfr27$L asfr28$L
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1    68        0    0.584    3.38     5.76     14.2     15.1     15.8     15.8      15.8     15.8     15.6
# 2     2    40        0    0.214    0.214    0.214     5.20     5.20     5.20     5.20    180.     180.     180.
```

Comment: Hmm - might be a rounding thing, but I'll look into it - thanks for pointing this out, and great solution you provided!